# Using url_for in tests

Tags: python, flask

I am writing some tests for a Flask application and am running into an issue where the URLs in my test_client responses do not match those produced by calling url_for from within the test case.  For example, I have the following in my template:

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="requestReport('{{ url_for('report') }}', '{{ session['email'] }}');">Report</a></li>
```

The response from the test_client renders this as:

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="requestReport('/api/report', 'user@domain.com');">Report</a></li>
```

I have a test case that checks to make sure this URL appears on a page under certain conditions:

```
self.client = self.app.test_client(use_cookies=True)
with self.app.app_context():
    page = self.client.get(url_for("index"), follow_redirects=True).data.decode()
    assert url_for("report") in page
```

The problem is that this test will fail even when the URL appears on the page, because the url_for call in the template is producing different output than the url_for call in my test case.  If I print url_for("report") from the test case code, I get:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/report
```

I have the SERVER_NAME key in app.config set to "localhost:5000" because if I do not have SERVER_NAME set the test case code will throw this error:

```
RuntimeError: Application was not able to create a URL adapter for request independent URL generation. You might be able to fix this by setting the SERVER_NAME config variable.
```

Obviously, I could work around this by hard-coding the URL in my test case code, but I would prefer to use URL_for so that future changes to my URL do not break my test code.

I have tried a couple different strings as SERVER_NAME, including "" which just generates a malformed URL that still doesn't match the one generated in the response.

Is there some way to fix this other than hard-coding the URL?

Answer (score 14):

For API testing, you can use `test_request_context`

```
class TestFlaskApi(unittest.TestCase):                                          
    def setUp(self):                                                            
        self.app = create_app()                                                 
        self.app_context = self.app.test_request_context()                      
        self.app_context.push()                                                 
        self.client = self.app.test_client() 

    def test_hello(self):                                                       
        response =  self.client.get(url_for('api.hello'),                       
                                    content_type='text')                        

        self.assertEqual(response.get_data(as_text=True), 'hello')
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use `url_for` in an application context like you do in your test code Flask automatically assumes you want to create an external link including the full host name (set in the `SERVER_NAME` config variable). Whereas the `url_for` in your template will create an internal link without the host name. So they won't match. To check for equality you need to explicitly set the `_external` property to `False`.

```
self.client = self.app.test_client(use_cookies=True)
with self.app.app_context():
    page = self.client.get(url_for("index"), follow_redirects=True).data.decode()
    assert url_for("report", _external=False) in page
```

Answer (score 4):

The top answer pushed the test request context but didn't pop it in `tearDown` method. The proper setup and teardown should like this:

```
class TestFlaskApi(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.context = self.app.test_request_context()
        self.context.push()  # push it
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.context.pop()  # pop it

    def test_hello(self):
        response =  self.client.get(url_for('api.hello'), content_type='text')
        self.assertEqual(response.get_data(as_text=True), 'hello')
```

If you are using **pytest**, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66314116/5511849).