# Generate URLs for Flask test client with url_for function

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, pytest

I'm trying to write unit tests for a Flask app using pytest. I have an app factory:

```
def create_app():
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')
    import os
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
    from models import db
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

And a test class:

```
class TestViews(object):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.app = create_app()
        cls.app.testing = True
        cls.client = cls.app.test_client()

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        cls.app_context.pop()

    def test_create_user(self):
        """
        Tests the creation of a new user.
        """
        view = TestViews.client.get(url_for('create_users')).status_code == 200
```

but when I run my tests I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.
```

Googling this tells me (I think) that using the test client should create an automatic application context. What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Making requests with the test client does indeed push an app context (indirectly). However, you're confusing the fact that `url_for` is visually inside the test request call with the idea that it is actually called inside. The `url_for` call is evaluated first, the result is passed to `client.get`.

`url_for` is typically for generating URLs *within* the app, unit tests are *external*. Typically, you just write exactly the URL you're trying to test in the request instead of generating it.

```
self.client.get('/users/create')
```

If you really want to use `url_for` here, you must do it in an app context. Note that when you're in an app context but not a request context, you must set the `SERVER_NAME` config and also pass `_external=False`. But again, you should probably just write out the URL you're trying to test.

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'localhost'

with self.app.app_context():
    url = url_for(..., _external=False)

self.client.get(url, ...)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call `url_for()` in test request context that created with `app.test_request_context()` method. There are three methods to achieve this.

#### With setup and teardown

Since you have created the setup and teardown method, just like what I normally do with unittest, you can just push a test request context in setup method then pop it in teardown method:

```py
class TestViews(object):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.app = create_app()
        cls.app.testing = True
        cls.client = cls.app.test_client()
        cls.context = cls.app.test_request_context()  # create the context object
        cls.context.push()  # push the context

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        cls.context.pop()  # pop the context

    def test_create_user(self):
        """
        Tests the creation of a new user.
        """
        view = TestViews.client.get(url_for('create_users')).status_code == 200
```

#### With pytest-flask

Besides, you can also just use [pytest-flask](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-flask). With pytest-flask, you can access to context bound objects (url_for, request, session) without context managers:

```
def test_app(client):
    assert client.get(url_for('myview')).status_code == 200
```

#### With autouse fixture

If you don't want to install the plugin, you can just use the following fixtures to do similar things (stolen from the source of pytest-flask):

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app('testing')
    return app


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _push_request_context(request, app):
    ctx = app.test_request_context()  # create context
    ctx.push()  # push

    def teardown():
        ctx.pop()  # pop

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)  # set teardown
```